# c#- listbox how to get listbox values by index

Tags: c#, wpf

I wantto know how to take list box values by index ? in my list box for first index i have content ="one"

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] n = new string[1];
    n[0] = listBox1.Items[0].ToString();
    txtbox1.Text = n[0];
}
```

Using above code when I get the first list box value it returns this:

**System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: one**

How can get only the content of the `listItem(index)`

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What is stored in your ListBox? Its possible you needed `GetValue` instead of ToString but then this returns an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit that i'm not familiar with WPF controls but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.90).aspx) shows it:

```
ListBoxItem lbi = listBox1.Items[0] as ListBoxItem; // cast object to ListBoxItem
txtbox1.Text = lbi.Content.ToString();
```

So you have to use the [`Content` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx) of the [`ListBoxItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx). You are using [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) which just returns the fully qualified name of the type if `ToString` was not overridden meaningfully.

If the `ListBox` is empty, you get an exception if you try to access the first item via index, the you have to check it first:

```
if(listBox1.HasItems)  // you can also use listBox1.Items.Count > 0
{
    ListBoxItem lbi = listBox1.Items[0];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @mahee: then ensure that you have an item. Edited my answer. Btw, _what_ exception did you get at all, an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or an `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 
  this is the error um getting

Comment: @mahee: sorry, should have copy-pasted from MSDN correctly. Edited my answer.

Comment: Its Working.... thank you very much TIM ... i spend hours to solve this .thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
n[0] = listBox1.Items[0].Content.ToString();
```

instead of

```
n[0] = listBox1.Items[0].ToString();
```

Because `.ToString()` on the `ListBox` just returns the control as string. You need to call `Text.ToString()` to when you want to get the text you can see as string.

Comment: There is no `Text` property in [`ListBoxItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem_properties(v=vs.110).aspx). Maybe you are referring to ASP.NET.

Comment: does not work for me Items[o].  they are suggesting only Equels/getHashcode/toString/get type

Comment: I'm looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx all the time and it works for me.. I'll take a deep look for you again....

Comment: ListBoxItem lbi = listBox1.Items[0] as ListBoxItem;                                                           
 txtbox1.Text = lbi.Content.ToString();                                                                     thnks for the help :)